# How to lookup the previous occurrence of a row's ID in another column, and get that previous occurrence row's value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-rolling

I have a large pandas dataframe of ~2million rows. Columns A and B are both ID columns, where ID==1 in Column A is the same ID entity as ID==1 in column B. Column C is the target value column.

Is there an efficient way, using pandas' native functions such as groupby etc or vectorisation methods, and avoiding looping, to:

For each row, lookup the previous occurrence in column A of row B's ID value, and get the previous occurrence row's column C value?

I've tried various groupby/rolling methods to no avail. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: a simple example will better

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of [`pd.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) and `pd.mul`.

A simple example:

```py
    A   B   C
0   2   4   48
1   1   3   14
2   4   4   19
3   5   5   20
4   4   3   20
5   1   3   41
6   3   2   45
7   2   2   34
8   1   2   44
9   1   4   43
```

Here, indices 6-9 contain IDs in column `B` that occur in previous rows of column `A`.  6 and 7 match with index 0, 8 matches with index 7 and 9 with index 4.

```py
# read data above
df = pd.read_clipboard()

# append "Out" column to df with the desired output
df["Out"] = pd.get_dummies(df.A) \
    .mul(df.C, axis=0).replace(0, method="ffill").shift() \
        .mul(pd.get_dummies(df.B)).max(axis=1).fillna(0)

df
#Out
#    A  B   C   Out
# 0  2  4  48   0.0
# 1  1  3  14   0.0
# 2  4  4  19   0.0
# 3  5  5  20   0.0
# 4  4  3  20   0.0
# 5  1  3  41   0.0
# 6  3  2  45  48.0
# 7  2  2  34  48.0
# 8  1  2  44  34.0
# 9  1  4  43  20.0
```

Breaking this down, the first step creates a pd.DataFrame of 1s and 0s for the IDs of column `A`.  Then this is multiplied by the values in column `C`:

```py
pd.get_dummies(df.A).mul(df.C, axis=0)
#     1   2   3   4   5
# 0   0  48   0   0   0
# 1  14   0   0   0   0
# 2   0   0   0  19   0
# 3   0   0   0   0  20
# 4   0   0   0  20   0
# 5  41   0   0   0   0
# 6   0   0  45   0   0
# 7   0  34   0   0   0
# 8  44   0   0   0   0
# 9  43   0   0   0   0
```

Zeros are forward-filled and the rows are shifted once (else index 7 in this example will return its own value in `C`).  The values are multiplied by the 1s and 0s of B:

```py
pd.get_dummies(df.A) \
    .mul(df.C, axis=0).replace(0, method="ffill").shift() \
        .mul(pd.get_dummies(df.B))
#     1     2    3     4    5
# 0 NaN   NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN
# 1 NaN   0.0  0.0   0.0  0.0
# 2 NaN   0.0  0.0   0.0  0.0
# 3 NaN   0.0  0.0   0.0  0.0
# 4 NaN   0.0  0.0   0.0  0.0
# 5 NaN   0.0  0.0   0.0  0.0
# 6 NaN  48.0  0.0   0.0  0.0
# 7 NaN  48.0  0.0   0.0  0.0
# 8 NaN  34.0  0.0   0.0  0.0
# 9 NaN   0.0  0.0  20.0  0.0
```

And finally the maximum value in each row will always be the matching (as all others will be `0` or `NaN`) - filling resulting `NaN` values with 0 for consistency.

Comment: Hi Rawson. Thanks for the thorough reply and sorry for the belated response. Your solution is neat, and I've tested that it indeed works on a smaller sample. The trouble is I run into an ArrayMemoryError because there are 4441 unique IDs:

`*** numpy.core._exceptions._ArrayMemoryError: Unable to allocate 63.5 GiB for an array with shape (4441, 1918168) and data type float64`

I will try to find a workaround incorporating your solution, but I'd appreciate any further comments